# While Loops in Ruby and Converting to a Function

Tags: ruby, function, loops, while-loop, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm on [Chapter 33](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex33.html) of Learn Ruby the Hard Way.

Extra credit exercise 1 asks:

> Convert this while loop to a function that you can call, and replace 6
>   in the test (i < 6) with a variable.

The code:

```
i = 0
numbers = []

while i < 6
  puts "At the top i is #{i}"
  numbers.push(i)

  i = i + 1
  puts "Numbers now: #{numbers}"
  puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
end

puts "The numbers: "

for num in numbers
  puts num
end
```

My attempt:

```
i = 0
numbers = []

def loops
while i < 6
  puts "At the top i is #{i}"
  numbers.push(i)

  i = i + 1
  puts "Numbers now: #{numbers}"
  puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
end
 end

 loops
 puts "The numbers: "

for num in numbers
  puts num
end
```

As you can see, I got as far as trying to make the block into a function, not yet making the 6 a variable.

Error:

```
ex33.rb:5:in `loops': undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object (Na
meError)
        from ex33.rb:15:in `<main>'
    from ex33.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Okay, improved it a little. Now the numbers variable is out of scope...

```
def loops (i, second_number)
numbers = []
while i < second_number
  puts "At the top i is #{i}"
    i = i + 1
  numbers.push(i)
  puts "Numbers now: #{numbers}"
  puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
end
 end

loops(0,6)
puts "The numbers: "

for num in numbers
  puts num
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @steenslag says, `i` is out of scope within `loops`. I would not recommend switching to using `@i` because `i` is only used by `loops`.

Your function is a utility that can be used to produce an array of numbers. The function uses `i` to figure out how far through it is (but the caller of the function doesn't care about this, it only wants the resulting `numbers`). The function also needs to return `numbers`, so move that inside `loops` too.

```
def loops
  i = 0
  numbers = []

  while i < 6
    puts "At the top i is #{i}"
    numbers.push(i)

    i = i + 1
    puts "Numbers now: #{numbers}"
    puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
  end
end
```

You now have to think about the fact that the caller of `loops` can no longer see `numbers`. Good luck with your learning.

Comment: I had just came up with a function with arguments that also replaces the 6 with a variable, I edited the OP with the code. However, as you said, now 'numbers' is out of sight...

Answer (score 0):

When you say `def`, `i` goes out of scope. The method can't "see" it. Use `@i` in stead (the @ gives the variable a greater "visibility"), or move the `i=6` inside the method, or figure out how to use parameters with a method.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misread the 'convert the while loop' but my solution was:

```
def loop(x, y)

   i = 0
   numbers = []

   while i < y
      puts "At the top i is #{i}"
      numbers.push(i)

      i += 1
      puts "Numbers now: ", numbers
      puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
   end

   puts "The numbers: "

# remember you can write this 2 other ways?
numbers.each {|num| puts num }

end

loop(1, 6)
```